# Xcode AutoLayout

Tags: xcode, autolayout, ios7

Здравствуйте. Я в IB сделал интерфейс с несколькими UILabel. Самый первый label - опциональный, то есть я могу в рантайме удалить его из view. 
Вот в чем вопрос, если я удалю первый label, то можно ли с помощью AutoLayout сделать так, чтобы второй label встал на место первого, третий на место второго и так далее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Была такая же задача: Сделал так:

1. Все "динамичныее" лауоаты убрал в UICollectionView.
2. Поставил минимальное значение height этому UICollectionView (смотри скрин)
3. Пристыковал константами сам CollectionView, а к нему следующий (с нулем) постояный вью.

И все работает :)

Скрин:

[image]

UPD:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightCell;
```

В Коде:

```
//build the View of CollectionView
if (_topNameArray.count == 3) {
  self.heightCell.constant = 206.0f;
}
if (_topNameArray.count == 4) {
  self.heightCell.constant = 228.0f;
}
[self.view updateConstraints];
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо :)

Comment: ЗАБЫЛ!!! Смотри нужно обязательно Саму константу высоты вывести как 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightCell; И уже ее изменять в коде!!!

Answer (score 0):

Решение с `UITableView` вам идеально подойдет, `UILabel`-ы уже есть в стандартных ячейках и их можно без труда удалять с красивой анимацией.

Не уверен, что есть красивое решение решение данной проблемы авторесайзными масками.

```
UILabe *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |  
                                               UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
mySupreView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
[mySupreView addSubview:myLabel];
```

Comment: Да нет, это не подойдет. У меня форма

Comment: UICollectionView?

Comment: @Alexander Sviridov, вот за это спасибо, посмотрю